# props are not being passed correctly when using React Navigation's headerTitle

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm using the stack screen like so:

```
<NavigationContainer>
<Stack.Navigator>
  /* There's also the stack screen for calling the Albums screen here as well. */
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Albums"
    component={Albums}
    options={{
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#191414",
      },
      headerTitle: (props) => <AlbumTitle {...props} />,
    }}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

AlbumTitle.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

class AlbumTitle extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default AlbumTitle;
```

And I'm calling the screen from a function and passing the props like this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Albums", {
  id,
  name,
});
```

Isn't this how it should be done? Once the function calls for the screen and passes the id and the name, when it renders, it should also pass the props to AlbumTitle so it shows the name, but it's not working like this, instead, `console.log(this.props)` is returning:

```
Object {
  "allowFontScaling": undefined,
  "children": "Albums",
  "onLayout": [Function anonymous],
  "style": undefined,
  "tintColor": undefined,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass props as such:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Albums"
  component={Albums}
  options={({ route }) => ({
    title: route.params.name,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#191414",
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      color: "white",
    },
  })}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought we can't add other options if we use the `options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.name })}` way, which was why `headerTitle: (props) => <AlbumTitle {...props} />,` inside `options` existed. Silly me, your code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this part of the documentation for showing dynamic title within your `AlbumTitle` component https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#using-params-in-the-title

```
  <Stack.Screen
        name="Albums"
        component={Albums}
        options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.name })}
      />
```

Basically, you need to set an option variable `title` and the get that title option with `props.children` in your `headerTitle` component

```
class AlbumTitle extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.children}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I already tried the above example before and it worked perfectly, without having AlbumTitle component. But how do I add other options like `headerStyle` if I use it?